# Copying large files(DB backups) 50GB+ to across the prod to dev environmetns

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage

We would like to copy Db backups from Prod to dev environemtns on monthly basis. But the files size  is around 50GB+. Is there any way we can do it quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, there's really no way to answer this objectively. Also, based on your tags, it's unclear exactly what you're trying to do. How does SharePoint relate to Blob Storage? Where are your backups? What is a "prod" and "dev" environment (it's unclear what you're copying, or how you're trying to copy, or if this is in Azure, and if so, if the environments are in the same region or different regions, etc)? What code have you written to do this? What issues are you running into? Also: things like "quickly" are really not quantifiable.

Comment: My  Database backups are in prod server drive. Previously i used Sharepoint to transfer files. the files size used to 20GB to 25 GB. But now some of files are even more than 45 GB+. While trying to upload those files to Share point it is taking lot of time as well failing everytime after some extint.

Comment: It's really important to edit your question with specific details, not add in comments. But... from your comment, this really seems like a non-programming question, and more of a data copy question more suitable for ServerFault. Just know that you need to include very specific details. Right now, even with your additional comment, it's not specific enough (e.g. "a lot of time" is very vague)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can try using ‘Azcopy’ utility in this case as  you can transfer/copy files from your Server’s drives to Azure Blob storage container or ADLS (Azure Data Lake Storage) Gen2 container. It transfers data at the maximum rate of 100 GB per hour in chunk size of 4 GB at a time when there is no capping of Internet bandwidth throughput limits.

To configure it for optimum performance, please use ‘Azcopy’ utility with ‘NC’ parameter as it means no concurrent requests are made to the Azcopy utility for file transfer. Also, ensure that the file size limit is at a time is set to less than 1TB at a time of transfer job.

Please refer the below link for more details on configuring the Azcopy utility for file transfer purposes and for optimal performance parameters: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-optimize#increase-concurrency

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggetions. I am using Azure blob storage explorer now for transferring the large files. Its fast and non interrupted approach in my view.